# Remove class after another one has been called jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using animations while scrolling on a website with animate.css and a JS script to check viewport. The scripts works, it appears but then disappears. I believe it is because the classes are added to the element but the original class "hidden" stays dominant once the animation has been called.

Here is the code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.fourth-right').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInRight',
            offset: 100
           });
    });
```

.hidden has `opacity:0` and .visible `opacity:1`

How do I remove the classe `hidden` once the animation has been called with `visible animated fadeInRight` ? I tried with .removeClass but I couldn't make it work, do you know why ? I also tried to set a `opacity:1!important` on .visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewportChecker plugin provides following option (source : [github](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker#options))

```
classToRemove: 'hidden', // Class to remove before adding 'classToAdd' to the elements
```